Django 1.8 and MSSQL 2022
Is there a way to connect a project in Django 1.8 to MSSQL 2022, using django_pyodbc_azure librery allows me connect to MSSQL 2016, is there another librery that allows me do this?

Yes, but don't. Django 1.8 is years out of support, and very insecure. I'm a contributor to both django-pyodbc-azure, and it's successor, mssql-django, and highly recommend upgrading to Django 4.2 (at least) before worrying about connecting to SQL Server. Here's the DB engine that'll work with Django 4.2 and above: https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-django
